# How can I find out what SQL Server tables are linked to MS Access?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, tablename

I inherited a MS Access front-end that has linked tables to SQL Server.  The linked table names in MS Access do not match the table names in SQL Server.  How can I find out what SQL server tables are actually linked to MS Access?  Also, if I didn't know what SQL Sever the linked tables were connected to, how could I find that out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the tabledefs collection to check the connect property and the source table name.

```
CurrentDB.TableDefs("dbo_table_name").SourceTableName
CurrentDB.TableDefs("dbo_table_name").Connect
```

Or

```
Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim db As Database

    Set db = CurrentDb

    For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        If tdf.Connect <> vbNullString Then
           Debug.Print tdf.Name; " -- "; tdf.SourceTableName; " -- "; tdf.Connect
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks!  This worked, but is there a way to also list the name of the MS Access link too?  Now that I have the SQL Server table names, I'm not sure what it is actually linked to in MS Access, since their names do not match.